About the form of ideals of $C(X)$ for $X$ compact and Hausdorff
This is my first question.
I have a problem that i can't solve. This is an exercise about Banach Algebras and ideals:
Let $X$ be a compact and T2 space. Consider:  $A = C(X)$.
For every non-empty closed  $S \subseteq X$ we define  $I_S = \{ f \in C(X) : f(x) = 0, \, \forall x \in S \} $.
This is a closed ideal.
I want to prove that $I_S$ is maximal if and only if  $S = \{x_0\}$.
I was able to prove one part. I showed that if $S = \{x_0\}$ then $I_S$ is maximal but I couldn't with the other implication.
Thanks for the help.

Hint: If $S\subseteq T$ then clearly $I_T\subseteq I_S$.

Suposse that $I_S$ is maximal but $S$ is a non-empty closed set such that $\lvert S\rvert≥ 2$. Take a fixed $z\in S$ and consider the ideal $I_{\left\{
z\right\}}$. Then, $I_S\subseteq I_{\left\{ z\right\}}$. Take another point $w\in S\setminus\{z \}$. As $X$ is $T_2$ and compact then $X$ is Tychonoff, and therefore, there exist $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ continuos such that $f(z)=0$ and $f(w)=1$. Thus, by definition, $f\in I_{\left\{ z\right\}}$ but $f\notin I_S$. Therefore, $I_S\subsetneq I_{\left\{ z\right\}}$, a contradiction!!! Thus, $0<\lvert S\rvert< 2$. We conclude that $\lvert S\rvert=1$, i.e., there exist $x_0\in X$ such that $S=\{x_0 \}$.
